# Laravel URL issues when using subdomains

Tags: php, laravel

just moved laravel over to my live site and hit errors straight away.

The errors are:

```
Warning: require(/var/sites/b/beta.buildsanctuary.com/public_html/local/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/sites/b/beta.buildsanctuary.com/public_html/local/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/sites/b/beta.buildsanctuary.com/public_html/local/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/sites/b/beta.buildsanctuary.com/public_html/local/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

Im not sure whats causing the issues, is it that its looking in the public_html folder for the files? when it should be just looking in the subdomains / the subdomain itself?

If that is the case... then how can i go about fixing this? if i change line 17 it changes the require location but not where its looking for the file (No such file or director in bla..)

The line 17 in question is:

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Yes.  If the path does not match, that would be a problem.  I think you answered your own question.

Comment: Just edited the question to be clearer. If the issue is the paths not matching I can change the require path, but how do I change the place its looking for? As in where it says 'No such file or directory in...'